# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar los espacios sin valores entre las barras de mi histograma?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

¿Cómo puedo eliminar los espacios sin valores entre las barras de mi histograma?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(RAM, 
   aes(x= X.g.mL,
       fill=AK))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
 geom_histogram()+
  labs(title="pendiente",
   subtitle = "pendiente",
   x="Concentración minima inhibitoria",
   y="Frecuencia") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Hello everybody]

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta, traducir el texto y poner el código. Entiendo que en este caso la imagen ayuda a visualizar el estado actual, pero si pegas el código en la pregunta será más fácil recibir respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias justos estaba pensando en eso

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme!!

Answer (score 4):

El problema parece ser que estás tratando a tu variable `X.g.mL` como si fuera continua, cuando en realidad parece más bien que fuera discreta, por lo que se ve son solo 4 valores. Te sugiero dos cambios:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(RAM, 
       aes(x= factor(X.g.mL),
           fill=AK))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_bar()+
  labs(title="pendiente",
       subtitle = "pendiente",
       x="Concentración minima inhibitoria",
       y="Frecuencia") +
  theme_bw()
```

1. Transforma `X.g.mL` en una variable discreta mediante `factor(X.g.mL)`
2. No uses un histograma, que va justamente mejor, con las variables continuas, sino un `geom_bar()`

Comment: Muchisimias gracias si se soluciono el problema.